# Setting default form object value from async call in Angular 2 using FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I'm using `"@angular/forms": "~2.1.0"` and `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3"` and am trying to set the default value of my `FormGroup`'s  (`campaignForm`)  `campaign_config_id` attribute after I've made an async call to get a list of `campaignConfigs`.

I've tried using the following as per another SO suggestion but I get `TypeError: _this.campaignForm.controls.campaign_config_id.updateValue is not a function`.

```
this.campaignConfigService.getCampaignConfigs()
  .subscribe(
    campaignConfigs => {
      ...
      this.campaignForm.controls['campaign_config_id'].updateValue(campaignConfigs[0].id)
    }
  );
```

I've also tried casting `this.campaignForm.controls['campaign_config_id']` into a `NgControl`, `FormControl`, `SelectControlValueAccessor` and other objects but none of them have an `.updateValue` function.

Any suggestions on how to best do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`updateValue()` is deprecated. Use `setValue()` instead for all kind of form controls.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most flexible way to deal with forms is using the "ReactiveForms" and create the form with the FormBuilder class.

Please study about reactive forms and FormGroup/FormBuilder and in the end you can do something like this: `this.form.controls['campaign_config_id'].setValue(yourIdValue)`